# Posso criar uma aplicação completa sem usar o swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Estou criando um sistema e surgiu uma dúvida!

Poderia criar formulários sem usar Swing, AWT ou as bibliotecas básicas no Java? Se eu usar outro framework, posso deixar de lado o Swing, AWT etc?

Qual melhor framework para trabalhar atualmente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nada te impede de usar um monte de `System.out.println` e `System.in` para fazer o seu sistema. Também há várias formas de não usar Swing e AWT, tais como recriar o equivalente a eles utilizando [Qt no Java](http://qtjambi.org/), [SDL no Java](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sdljava/) ou coisa parecida.

Outra coisa é que o Android e o Java ME também têm interfaces gráficas feitas totalmente por fora do AWT e do Swing.

Também é de se notar que atualmente temos o JavaFX (embora ele use grandes partes do Swing por debaixo dos panos).

Uma outra possibilidade é trabalhar-se com interfaces web com HTML5 e javascript e usar o Java na parte do servidor. Se for para uma solução web, pode-se utilizar JSP, JSF, primefaces, GWT ou vários outros frameworks web disponíveis para isso.

Entretanto, o grande ponto disso é saber por que você não quer usar o AWT e/ou o Swing? Qual caso você tem em mente que faz com que eles sejam inservíveis ao que você quer?

Perguntar qual é o melhor framework é uma pergunta meramente opinativa: o que eu considero o melhor pode não ser o que você considere. Além disso, sem especificar-se detalhes sobre o sistema que você quer construir, essa pergunta fica genérica demais para poder ser respondida de forma construtiva e objetiva.

Comment: Melhor framework podemos assumir em números de downloads ou popularidade, e também flexibilidade, mas queira saber dos mais flexíveis mesmo, a dinâmica do uso influencia alterações, foi esse o motivo da pergunta, pois sei que muitos elementos compartilhados e prontos do java não permitem alteração nenhuma. Quero ter maior autonomia em meu projeto e com o swing ou awt não terei essa flexibilização.